# Why does Auto_Increment return null?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment

I'm writing a web application that will insert new records into a MySQL database table. Most of the information is user-supplied, except for the primary key, which I want to obtain using Auto_Increment. When I run the following query from my web application:

```
SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='charlist';
```

It returns nothing - I checked by storing the result of the query in a variable and then `echo`ing that variable, and nothing was output. I also used the MySQL console to run this query, and it returned this:

```
+----------------+
| Auto_Increment |
+----------------+
|           NULL |
+----------------+
```

My table definitely has a primary key field, and it has 5 records with the primary key field filled in. This is the structure of the table.

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| bookIntroduced | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pageIntroduced | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title          | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| forename       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| surname        | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| oldSurname     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| alias          | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| regnalNumber   | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And this is a few fields of the 5 records already in the table.

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | forename  | surname |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | Waymar    | Royce   |
|  3 | Mance     | Rayder  |
|  4 | Gared     |         |
|  5 | Tristifer | Mudd    |
|  6 | Edric     | Dayne   |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

So why would Auto_Increment return NULL, when there are records in the table with a valid primary key?

Answer (score 5):

Your key is Primary Key but is not set as auto increment.
Please alter your table like

```
ALTER TABLE `charlist`     CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Comment: That's fantastic, the auto_increment query now works correctly in the MySQL console. I'm having trouble getting it to work with PHP though, I'll come back if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I can't figure it out. I've tried to put the result of the auto_increment into a variable, but when I echo the variable, again I get nothing. `$id = $conn->query("SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='$tablename'");`

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a typo in there, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

because the `id` column is not marked default as `auto_increment`.

Comment: is it possible to select autoincrement?

Comment: just run in sql ``alter table `charlist` change `id` `id` INT(11) not null auto_increment;`` or just look @shahzad answer